# iTextSharp merge method produces empy form fields (now duplicate values with fields rename not working)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using a straight forward method to merge multiple PDF files into one, however running it produces one single file with form fields being emptied, I have used different versions of the iTextSharp dll, old and new butthe same results.

I have even used the open source version in order to get internal silent exception but not issues there, searching the web and stackoverflow doesnt mention anything about the fields getting emptied.

```
      public MemoryStream MergePdfForms(List<byte[]> files)
            {
                if (files.Count > 1)
                {
                    using (System.IO.MemoryStream msOutput = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document())
                        {
                            using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy pCopy = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy(doc, msOutput) { PdfVersion = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7 })
                            {
                                doc.Open();
                                foreach (var oFile in files)
                                {
                                    using (iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfFile = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(oFile))
                                    {
                                        for (int i = 1; i <= pdfFile.NumberOfPages; i++)
                                        {
                                            pCopy.AddPage(pCopy.GetImportedPage(pdfFile, i));
                                            pCopy.FreeReader(pdfFile);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        return msOutput;
                    }
                }
                else if (files.Count == 1)
                {
                    return new System.IO.MemoryStream(files[0]);
                }

                return null;
            }
 Any Idea what Im doing wrong here?
```

**UPDATE**

After suggestion below the merge is working, but renaming fields does not do the job, fields with the same name in multiple dpocument always get the value of the first field appearing in the list, so if I have firstName field in PDF all firstName fields in the PDF will have the same value, even after the rename as below:

```
public byte[] MergeFiles(IList<DBForms> forms, string ctpId)
{
    if (documents.Count < 1)
        return null;

    System.IO.MemoryStream msOutput = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, msOutput);
    copy.SetMergeFields();
    document.Open();
    List<PdfReader> readers = new List<PdfReader>();

    foreach (var docData in forms.Where(d => d.Status != 2))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FlattenRenamePdfForm(docData.DocumentFile));
        readers.Add(reader);
        copy.AddDocument(reader);

    }
    document.Close();

    foreach (PdfReader reader in readers)
    {
        reader.Close();
    }

    return msOutput.ToArray();
}

private byte[] FlattenRenamePdfForm(byte[] oldDoc)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldDoc);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
        {
            ICollection<string> keys = stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Keys;

            List<string> keysCopy = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                keysCopy.Add(key);
            }

            foreach (var key in keysCopy)
            {
                stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
                stamper.AcroFields.RenameField(key, String.Format("{0}{1}", key, new Guid()));

            }

            stamper.Close();
        }
        reader.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: All version of iText are open source, so I don't understand your comment "I've even tried the open source version." Also: did you try iText 7? I'm pretty sure you tried either iTextSharp 4 or iTextSharp 7. In any case: your code is wrong. See http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-merge-forms-different-files-one-pdf to understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Thanks Bruno, your suggestion does work to merge but rename seems not working, I have used the rename procedure you suggested elsewhere in the rename method above but that doesnt seem to work, updated code is above, does it look right to you?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have moved the update into a new question for clarity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019252/itextsharp-fields-rename-does-not-work-with-merge