# iTextSharp fields rename does not work with Merge

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation

This is a follow up to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003264/itextsharp-merge-method-produces-empy-form-fields-now-duplicate-values-with-fie) I had earlier, after the merge of PDF files with form fields worked successfully, if fields with same names do appear then they are not getting their distinct values from their original documents, it looks like a field with the same name propagate its values to the following fields which have the same name.

This is the code to merge and rename in 2 separate functions:

```
public byte[] MergeFiles(IList<DBForms> forms)
{
    if (forms.Count < 1)
        return null;

    System.IO.MemoryStream msOutput = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, msOutput);
    copy.SetMergeFields();
    document.Open();
    List<PdfReader> readers = new List<PdfReader>();

    foreach (var docData in forms.Where(d => d.Status != 2))
    {
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(FlattenRenamePdfForm(docData.DocumentFile));
        readers.Add(reader);
        copy.AddDocument(reader);

    }
    document.Close();

    foreach (PdfReader reader in readers)
    {
        reader.Close();
    }

    return msOutput.ToArray();
}

private byte[] FlattenRenamePdfForm(byte[] oldDoc)
{
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(oldDoc);
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms))
        {
            ICollection<string> keys = stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Keys;

            List<string> keysCopy = new List<string>();

            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                keysCopy.Add(key);
            }

            foreach (var key in keysCopy)
            {
                stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(key, "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
                stamper.AcroFields.RenameField(key, String.Format("{0}{1}", key, new Guid()));

            }

            stamper.Close();
        }
        reader.Close();
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This is done when using the latest iTextSharp library, 5.5.10, the test is done on the w8Ben documents

Here are the files

**First**

[image: First PDF]

**Second**

[image: Second PDF]

**Merged**

[image: Merged PDF]

Comment: Have you tried JSON?

Comment: The latest iTextSharp version is actually 5.5.11, but ok. :)

Comment: You appear to merge copies of the same form. Thus, the identifiers of the corresponding fields of both forms are the same. In PDF, though, all visible form fields with the identical identifier are interpreted to represent the same abstract form field and in particular have the same value. Thus, you have to rename the fields of one form or to really flatten the forms before merging to prevent this.

Comment: @mkl thats what the whole question all about, rename method does not work, please read the question

Comment: Right. Please share the PDFs in question.

Comment: I see that the name of the method you created is `FlattenRenamePdfForm`. If you want to *flatten* the form eventually, it is better to do so before merging the filled out forms. In that case, there is no need to rename the fields. If you do have to rename the field, we'd probably have to take a look inside the document.

Comment: @mkl They are the IRS documents, available on https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw8ben.pdf

Comment: @BrunoLowagie That method seems to not really flatten but merely set the fields read-only.

Comment: @Maya That form is a hybrid AcroForm/XFA document. I would recommend removing the XFA part,

Comment: What @mkl means is explained here: [Is it safe to remove XFA?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/it-safe-remove-xfa) and [RemoveXFA.java](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples-itext5/xfa-examples#758-removexfa.java)